# How Do You Set DOTNET_SHARED_STORE for a function deployed with CloudFormation?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda-layers

We are creating a lambda layer in codebuild using the command we are using is `dotnet lambda publish-layer`.

Then we do a

```
dotnet lambda package with --function-layers (layer arn)
```

This command shows a warning:

> Warning: You must set the DOTNET_SHARED_STORE environment variable when deploying the package. If not set the layers specified will not be located by the .NET Core runtime. The trailing '/' is required.`

We then deploy the function using CF with a `AWS::Lambda::Function` and set an lambda environment variable on the function of `DOTNET_SHARED_STORE` to `/opt/dotnetcore/store/`

But, in the function's CloudWatch log, we get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Amazon.Lambda.Core'

The documentation reads as below:

The .NET Core runtime in Lambda needs to be configured to look for the NuGet assemblies from the layer. This is done by setting the DOTNET_SHARED_STORE environment variable to the paths of where the runtime package store layer will be extracted. If multiple layers are used with different opt directories then each directory should be added to the environment variable separated by colons. A trailing / is required for the DOTNET_SHARED_STORE .NET Core environment variable.

The other weird part is the error

> Unhandled exception. `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Amazon.Lambda.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

We are using `Amazon.Lambda.Core Version 2.1.0`.

The layer manifest has

```
<Package Id="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
```

The function failing has no direct reference to `Amazon.Lambda.Core` but includes `<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CloudFront" Version="3.7.4.39" />` which depends on `Amazon.Lambda.Core 3.7.11.13`

What might we be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope,  no support via github issues either.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and adding an environment variable for DOTNET_SHARED_STORE=/opt/dotnetcore/store/ on the lambda function solved the issue. I am uploading updated code for the function on s3, and running terraform to update the function. Hope this might help